# Check if received more or less than one message

Tags: qt, communication, message, data-transfer, qtcpsocket

I need to make simple chat application using QTcpSocket and QTcpServer. I understand I should put message size in the beginning of the message to check message bounds. But how should I handle the cases when application receives only part of the message or more than one message?

Or there could be the case when application at first receives incomplete message and after that receives another message. In that situation both messages would be combined in one and only part of second message would be recognized.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. Data from single reading could be incomplete. [Read this entry](http://www.binarytides.com/receive-full-data-with-recv-socket-function-in-c/).
You can make up your own protocol for correct data transfer.
Let`s imagine that you have to send text message. You could do it in the next way:
First 4 bytes - message size, next bytes - message.
When you receive first piece of data you can analyze it and understand hove many bytes you are waiting for. When you read all data from the first message, beginning of the next message will contain full message size in the firs 4 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

If your messages have a defined data type (or a series of defined types) and you use Qt >=5.7 then you can use transactions.

The typical example is if your message is a QString (imagine a JSON or XML) you can write it using `QDataStream` as always, then you read it you can use:

```
 QString messageString;
 QDataStream stream(socket);
 stream.startTransaction();
 stream >> messageString;
 if(stream.commitTransaction()){
 // The message was received in full
 }
```